# limiting fields returned from a mongoid polymorphic relation

Tags: mongoid

I have a polymorphic relation in mongoid like the following one:

```
class Company
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  has_many :posts, as: :postable
end

class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  has_many :posts, as: :postable
end

class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :postable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I would like to sometimes (and not most of the time) load only some fields of the postable. In a non polymorphic relation (say only a Person has posts) I can do:

```
Person.only(:name).find(some_post.postable_id)
```

But is this possible in a polymorphic relation?

Comment: Can you say what document or query you want ?

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few ways of doing this but I am not sure which is the best. Complex relations are not a strength MongoDB and other NoSQLs and queries can get expensive if you start scanning multiple documents for your answers.

Using where:

```
Person.where(name: "name").posts.where(postable_id: "id")
```

Finding the parent from the post:

```
Post.where(id: "id").person.only(:name)
```

(note that postable_id and id are not the same value!)

However, be careful. If all you are doing is listing posts you are probably better off including the person's name in the post and writing a callback to update the person's name if they change their name. Alternatively, if you are linking to comments from a person why not include the comment IDs (or enough data to make the link) in the Person model so you can get all comments with one document call. Similarly if you are getting a count, use a callback to make a post count in the Person model so you aren't mapping hundreds of Posts every time.

I hope this helps, if not provide me with some more information and I'll update this.